# Upload file with GraphQl+ReScript

Tags: graphql, rescript

Does anyone work with ApolloGraphQl + Rescript?
I struggle with uploading files.
How to implement [apollo-upload-client](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client) ?
As I understand I should modify httpLink using the [createUploadLink](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client#function-createuploadlink), and this function change content-type in my request.

```
let httpLink = ApolloClient.Link.HttpLink.make(~uri=_ => Env.graphqlEndpoint, ())
........................................
let client = {
  open ApolloClient
  make(
    ~cache=Cache.InMemoryCache.make(),
    ~connectToDevTools=true,
    ~defaultOptions=DefaultOptions.make(
      ~mutate=DefaultMutateOptions.make(~awaitRefetchQueries=true, ~errorPolicy=All, ()),
      ~query=DefaultQueryOptions.make(~fetchPolicy=NetworkOnly, ~errorPolicy=All, ()),
      ~watchQuery=DefaultWatchQueryOptions.make(~fetchPolicy=NetworkOnly, ~errorPolicy=All, ()),
      (),
    ),
    ~link=ApolloClient.Link.from([authTokenContextLink, httpLink]),
    (),
  )
}
```

If someone helps me with it I’ll be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
@module("apollo-upload-client")
external createUploadLink: {"uri": string} => ApolloClient.Types.ApolloLink.t = "createUploadLink"

let uploadLink = createUploadLink({"uri": "..."})
```

and one of my mistakes was that I tried to use my own types for File instead of standard Js.Json.t when got the data from the input